# Запуск этого устройства невозможен. (Код 10)

Tags: windows, видеокарта

стандартный vga графический адаптер windows 7 Запуск этого устройства невозможен. (Код 10) Помогите!!! Месяц назад выскочил синий экран ,а после загрузки появилась ошибка 43
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стань курсором на проблемный адаптер, правый клик, Удалить; Перезагрузи компьютер; Снова зайди в диспетчер устройств посмотри, - проблемный адаптер должен исчезнуть !

Comment: Здравствуйте,установил драйвера ,у меня появилась новая ошибка 43

Comment: см https://spec-komp.com/news/oshibka_43_reshenie_problemy/2017-09-28-1104